# Material-UI get all rows from DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know how to get all row data from Material-UI `DataGrid`? For example, I changed some values inside `DataGrid` rows and want to get all my rows after making changes. Example:

```
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import moment from "moment";

const columns = [
  {
    field: "Col1",
    headerName: "Col1",
    flex: 1.0,
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    sortable: false,
    disableColumnMenu: true
  },
  {
    field: "Col2",
    headerName: "Col2",
    flex: 1.0,
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    sortable: false,
    disableColumnMenu: true,
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <>
        <TextField
          type="date"
          defaultValue={moment(Date.parse(params.row.Date)).format(
            "YYYY-MM-DD"
          )}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
        />
      </>
    )
  },
  {
    field: "Col3",
    headerName: "Col3",
    flex: 1.0,
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    sortable: false,
    disableColumnMenu: true,
    renderCell: (params) => <TextField />
  }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, Col1: "col1 data", Col2: null, Col3: null },
  { id: 2, Col1: "col2 data", Col2: null, Col3: null },
  { id: 3, Col1: "col3 data", Col2: null, Col3: null }
];

export default function App() {
  const handleClickButton = () => {
    console.log(rows); //I want to see grid changed data
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataGrid
        density="compact"
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={25}
        autoHeight={true}
        hideFooter={true}
      />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClickButton}>
        Show me grid data
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 66726455/material-ui-get-all-rows-from-datagrid]

Comment: please elaborate. Show us some code and what exactly you mean.

Comment: I've aded the example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Material-UI's `DataGrid` stores the row data internally and has [its own API](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rows/#apiref) to modify the row data. This is how you update the row data when `onChange` fires:

```js
{
  field: "Col3",
  headerName: "Col3",
  renderCell: (params) => (
    <TextField
      onChange={(e) =>
        params.api.updateRows([{ ...params.row, Col3: e.target.value }])
      }
    />
  )
}
```

In version 5, you only need to mark column as `editable`. (See [cell editing](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#cell-editing))

```
{
  field: "Col3",
  headerName: "Col3",
  editable: true
}
```

To read the current row state of `DataGrid`, you can use `apiRef.current.getRowModels()`. But `apiRef` comes from `Material-UI X Pro`. If you still want to access it, you have to use the following hack:

```js
function useApiRef() {
  const apiRef = useRef(null);
  const _columns = useMemo(
    () =>
      columns.concat({
        field: "__HIDDEN__",
        width: 0,
        renderCell: (params) => {
          apiRef.current = params.api;
          return null;
        }
      }),
    [columns]
  );

  return { apiRef, columns: _columns };
}
```

#### Usage

```js
const { apiRef, columns } = useApiRef();
const handleClickButton = () => {
  console.log(apiRef.current.getRowModels());
};

return (
  <>
    <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    <Button onClick={handleClickButton}>
      Show data
    </Button>
  </>
);
```

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66726455/material-ui-get-all-rows-from-datagrid]

Comment: Good solution, thanks! Do you know is there a method like apiRef.current.getRowModels() but to get selectionModel?

Comment: @RuslanErmahgerd Try [`apiRef.current.getSelectedRows()`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/9230c5ac57fbe52f4a0ea79c7fa38058b3c48090/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/models/api/gridSelectionApi.ts#L27)

Comment: So there is no way to get the edited data out of the datagrid apart from using the paid version or hacking it?

Comment: @QiongWu If you want to get the [edited data](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#main-content) before it's committed there is other way to do that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69620833/9449426) answer for more detail.

Comment: thanks! and after its committed? how would I get it then?

Comment: Is it possible to use the same approach in new @mui/x-data-grid? In new version "__HIDDEN__" field is not hidden, and if I hide it using property 'hide: true' than it not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

1.converte component TextField to controlled component

```
<TextField
    onChange={(e) =>
      updateRows(e.target.value, params.row.id, params.field)
    }
  />
```

2.update rows when changes

```
const updateRows = (value, id, field) => {
  const item = rows.find((item) => item.id === id);
  item[field] = value;
  console.log(rows);
};
```

3. get all you need from rows