# How to update editedRows from DataGrid MUI to firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, datagrid, material-ui

How can I update the values I just edit to firebase?
So far this is what I understand from editRow (correct me if I'm wrong).

**Inside DataGrid**

```
//Enable edit mode for row and not cell
editMode="row"

//any update you do in the row is stored in this variable so when you finish it overrides
//w/e you had there with editRowsModel value
editRowsModel={editRowsModel}

//Calls for the function that will be handeling the updates and the all the updates into "model"
onEditRowsModelChange={handleEditRowsModelChange}

//For Double Click + Control 
//(That way if uses double click by mistake it doesn't enable editMode)
onCellDoubleClick={(params, event) => {
        if (!event.ctrlKey) {
          event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
        }
      }}
```

**Const**

```
//Variable that will hold the edited variable
const [editRowsModel, setEditRowsModel] = React.useState({});

//Edit function
const handleEditRowsModelChange = React.useCallback((model) => {
  setEditRowsModel(model);
}, []);
```

Now in the Edit function is where I'm suppose to edit the row but how can I update to firebase?
Like I have this:

```
const [editRowsModel, setEditRowsModel] = React.useState({});
const handleEditRowsModelChange = React.useCallback((model) => {
  setEditRowsModel(model);
  console.log(model.uid)
  /*
   estudiantes.filter( x => {
     const temporalQuery = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes").doc(x.uid);
     temporalQuery.update({
       nombre: model.nombre,
       colegio: model.colegio,
       grado: model.grado
      })
    })
*/
}, []);
```

however this will not work because I can't see the individual values from model because it just say "undefined" otherwise this would work. How can I get the individual values of model ?

and because is undefined I'll get an error when I try that code.

[image]

Any help/tips is welcome.

**How the model logs**

```
console.log(model)
console.log(model.name)
console.log(model[0].name)
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to detect when the user finishs editing and get the submitted data to update on firebase, am I correct?

Comment: I can see the value at all time if I just console.log the "model", model shows the whole row data but idk how to individually take this data if that makes sense ? because I can't just simply do model[0].name or something like that as I have done before it comes out as undefined let me upload how it prints

Comment: `individually take this data`, you mean when the user enter or submit the new row data?

Comment: When I enters edit mode the model automatically stores the row data and I want to take that data to update the firebase, but it shows it as undefined when I try to log "parts of the array". idk if I'm explaining my self properly

Comment: The edit model is not an array, it's an object where the key is the row id and the value is the edited row data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but if you want to access the editing row data, this is how you can do it:

```
const [editRowsModel, setEditRowsModel] = React.useState({});
const [editRowData, setEditRowData] = React.useState({});

const handleEditRowsModelChange = React.useCallback(
  (model) => {
    const editedIds = Object.keys(model);

    // user stops editing when the edit model is empty
    if (editedIds.length === 0) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(editRowData, null, 4));
      // update on firebase
    } else {
      setEditRowData(model[editedIds[0]]);
    }

    setEditRowsModel(model);
  },
  [editRowData]
);

console.log(editRowData);

return (
  <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      editMode="row"
      editRowsModel={editRowsModel}
      onEditRowsModelChange={handleEditRowsModelChange}
    />
  </div>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Yeah this should work I just need to figure out how to get the UID of the nested document I will post an answer with the update integrated later as soon as I found out

Comment: In the end I found an issue with firebase but idk why it doesn't make sense rip

Comment: Ah I found the issue so I though `editRowData` was parsing the data back correctly however I was wrong, it comes as an `Object, Object`. However when I try to do the following `let tempUID = JSON.stringify(editRowData.uid)` it also comes wrong it comes as value: "the uid presented" is there a way to remove the "word" value and just bring the numbers from the value if that makes sense ? It literally comes up like this: `{"value":"Gb4QwckjwnhTVfhCf2gw"}`

Comment: got it working all I had to do was to call it as editRowData.uid.value